# Python - converting List to Tuple and compare(for loop)

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
def run(lst, tup):
    tup_1 = ()
    for x in range(len(lst)):
        tup_1[x] = lst[x]

    if tup_1[1] == lst[1]:
        return True
        for y in range(len(tup_1)):
            if tup_1[y] == tup[y]:
                return "matched"
            else:
                return "not equal"
print run([1,2,3],(1,2,3))
```

I tried to convert number in List to Tuple form, so I can compare with another tuple.
But the problem is it returns an error like this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 16, in
>      File "", line 5, in run TypeError: 'tuple' object
>   does not support item assignment

Comment: `tup_1 = tuple(lst)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a list to tuple with `tuple` function like this

```
tuple(lst)
```

And to check if a list and tuple are the same, you can simply do this

```
return tuple(lst) == tup
```

Comment: I understand it's immutable, but I was trying to assign value into them using for loop. The purpose is to examine the value being assigned in the loop so I can further validate it. Because IIRC, tuple can be assign right? when it's empty at first. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @vincentChen Nope... You cannot assign values to tuple elements, as it is immutable. What you can do is, you can extend tuples with `+` operator

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because tuples are immutable, data inside them cannot be mutated

*example:*

```
>>> t = (1,2,3)
>>> t[1] = 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

---

Unlike lists which are mutable:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> l[1] = 4
>>> l
[1, 4, 3]
```

---

So use a list instead of a tuple:

```
tup_1 = []
```

If you need to convert a list to a tuple you can use the built-in [`tuple()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) function

*For more information I recommend you read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)*

Comment: yeah, but I was practicing tuple, and my purpose is to assign/copy values in List to Tuple using for loop. So I can validate it each time the loop trying to assign value into new tuple. Please correct me if I'm wrong